# CoreNFC available on which Apple devices

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta, iphone7plus

Hi I want to know on which Apple devices CoreNFC works.
On https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc there are only [Apple Developer Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjpwe.png) iPhone 7 and 7plus. 
iPad or Apple Watch doesn't support yet?

Comment: Yeah..You have the answer in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.. You read is exactly correct**

NFC support is added only for iphone 7 and iphone 7 plus. for other device you still need to wait 
[image]